# How is the sample space of a random variable defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

I was watching this example where the professor said that if we have 2 i.i.d RVs, both of them being binomial random variables, then we can only add them up if their sample spaces are the same. I am wondering what the meaning is of a sample space for a random variable?

Comment: Presumably your text (or lecture notes) contain a definition of a random variable.  In any case, you can look at standard references, like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)

Comment: The sample space here means the domain of the RVs; of course if you have RVs on two different sample spaces (like coin flips and dice rolls) adding them doesn't really make sense (without some tweaking- admittedly not a lot of tweaking. Yeah this is a bad example in retrospect as @JackM points out)

Comment: @Vercingetorix That's not a great example, of course you can add coin flips and dice rolls (and you can even model them as having a common sample space).

Comment: Fair enough. Bad example

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition of a (real) random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space. The sample space is, in informal terms, where the "randomness" of probability comes from.

For example, say you flip a fair coin $5$ times. Then the sample space $\Omega$ is the set of your possible outcomes, e.g. $HHHHH$, $THTTH$ etc.

A random variable $X$ in this space might e.g. be the number of heads you toss. So for example, $X(HHHHH)=5$.

It makes no sense to add two random variables with different sample spaces in the same way it makes no sense to add two functions with different *domains*. This is because just as with functions, we *define* $X+Y$ by $$(X+Y)(\omega)=X(\omega)+Y(\omega),$$ for $\omega\in\Omega$. Evidently we require $X$ and $Y$ to have the same sample space.

As an example, consider $X$ and $\Omega$ as defined by the coin tosses, and consider a new random variable $X':\Omega'\to\mathbb R$. The sample space $\Omega'$ is the set of points on Earth, and $X'$ is the current temperature at a point on the Earth. What is $X+X'$?

The situtation can be salvaged though. Suppose $X$, $Y$ are real random variables with sample spaces $\Omega_X$, $\Omega_Y$. Define a random variable $Z:\Omega_X\times\Omega_Y\to\mathbb R$ by $$Z(\omega_X,\omega_Y)=X(\omega_X)+Y(\omega_Y).$$
Then the projections $\bar{X}:(\omega_X,\omega_Y)\mapsto X(\omega_X)$ and $\bar{Y}:(\omega_X,\omega_Y)\mapsto Y(\omega_Y)$ have the same distributions as $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and clearly $\bar{X}+\bar{Y}=Z$ is defined. In fact, $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are even independent.