Expected value of Binomial Distribution using Linearity of Expectation.
I know the Binomial random variable is the number of successes in n independent Bernoulli trials. And we tend to find the expected value of Binomial RV by setting it up as the sum of Bernoulli RV.
$X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$.
Where each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli RV / Indicator RV that takes on 1(success) with prob $p$ and 0 with prob $1-p$.
Intuitively, yes, $X$ will capture the number of successes in the independent Bernoulli trials, but I want to connect this to the fundamental definition of RV.
A random variable is a function that takes the sample space to a Reals (generally).
What is the sample space of $X$ (Binomial RV) the sample space for the Bernoulli is {Success, Failure}
And in this post Proof of linearity for expectation given random variables are dependent, I read If $X$ and $Y$ are both random variables of the same sample space, then so is their sum. So is the sample space of Binomial also $\text{\{Success,Failure}\}$.
Shouldn't it be $\text{\{Success,Failure}\}^n$?

Yes, the sample space is ${ \text{success}, \text{failure} }^n$.

The sample spaces for $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are not ${\text{success},\text{failure}}$. Those would be appropriate sample spaces if we considered them in isolation, but if we want to consider them as independent random variables then they all have to have the sample space ${\text{success},\text{failure}}^n$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3969578/137524 for a nice discussion of this point.
